# Exiting the airport without passing through customs - was this a mistake?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, airports

I was at Cebu International Airport. It was my first time travelling and I didn't know what to do. I got my luggage and exited the airport without passing through customs. How serious is this mistake?

Comment: To sum up: it's extremely unlikely you could do that. Maybe you didn't realize you went through the green corridor but unless you have snuck through some side door you did go through customs. And airports are reasonably good at keeping those doors closed.

Comment: The custom is sometime not very noticeable, just after getting the baggage. On small airports is just one desk and often with nobody (LCY)